# Is there a way to set to Combo element(PySimpleGuiQt's) with text and value to each option? (Something like HTML's option list)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combobox, pysimplegui

```
[sg.Combo(someListOfNames, someListOfObjects)]
```

If I would call `values[0]`, I will only get the `someListOfNames`'s picked index value, I want to get `someListOfObjects`'s value of the same index of `someListOfNames` which the index picked by the user on the GUI.

I tried setting it in different ways for example:

```
[sg.Combo(someListOfNames, values=someListOfObjects)]
```

(Returned `TypeError: Combo.__init___() got multiple values for argument 'values'`

Also I've tried `default-value` and other var names I found at Combo's class or documention but none seems to work.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but isn't this what a dictionary does? Map one thing to another. It's used extensively in the demos with Listboxes for example, where a filename maps to a full absolute filename.

Answer (score 1):

Use only the `someListOfNames` in the `Combo` function, then use `index` function to find its index, and get the object from `someListOfObjects` with that index.

```
[sg.Combo(someListOfNames)]
selectedObjectByName = someListOfObjects[(someListOfNames.index(values[0]))]
```